# Override DrawRect for a UIView inside a UIViewController in a storyboard

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, drawrect

I am using storyboards.

I have a UIViewController with a UIView

I want to do some custom drawing in the UIView

So I think I can create a IBOutlet for the UIView in my UIViewController class.
Where do I put my code for overriding the drawRect for the UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of UIView and implement drawRect method.

In storyboard, assign the subclass of the UIView in Class inspector of the control.